# Java - Explicit method call for a generic class?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, generics, syntax

I am following a free google appengine programming course at udacity ([Developing Scalable Apps In java](https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-scalable-apps-in-java--ud859), a pretty good introductory course to appengine by the way).

In one of the lessons, I get to this sample piece of java code:

```
...
// Iterate over keyStringsToAttend and return a Collection of the
// Conference entities that the user has registered to attend
List< Key<Conference> > keysToAttend = new ArrayList<>();
for ( String keyString : keyStringsToAttend ) {
      keysToAttend.add( Key.<Conference>create( keyString ) );
}
...
```

My question is about the last statement in the fragment:

```
Key.<Conference>create( keyString )
```

The syntax is correct, it compiles and runs perfectly, but I just don't get the meaning of the `.<Conference>` part before the `create(...)` method name...
Can you explain this syntax?

Comment: That is Generics, too broad topic, Please google "Generics" and read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The create method accepts generic parameter, so the parameter type was passed.

you can read more about generic parameters [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)

Comment: Thanks Sunil, useful answer! As you may guess, I am quite new to java. I have a good background on C++, which has a similar syntax for generics. Similar... but not equal!